# 2D std::array , stack overflow exception

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio, stl

I am having speed issues with the C++ standard arrays , so I am testing using the stl::array for computation, to see how fast it is.

I define a two dimensional array of the struct PAPoint (see below) and attempt to create a 2D array of it. It compiles ok, but when I try to run I get a Stack overflow (literally) exception. 2D arrays with size 200x200 run ok but not 500x500. Is there a solution? Is the stack really that small?

Thank you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cmath>

#define PAWIDTH 500 //STACK OVERFLOW FOR LARGE NUMBERS
#define PAHEIGHT 500

struct PApoint{
    float elpotential = 0;
    bool iselectrode = false;
}
;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "SpeedTestEMLaplaceSolver.cpp using 2D std::array of PApoint\n";
    std::array< std::array<PApoint, PAWIDTH>, PAHEIGHT> myPAArray; //Array is allocated in the stack so large arrays can trigger stack overflow
    //Gives error in chkstk.asm
    /*
    Unhandled exception at 0x00827659 in SpeedTestEMLaplaceSolver.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x00402000). occurred
    */
}
```

Comment: Allowing for 8-byte alignment of the elements, your array is 500 x 500 x 8 bytes in size = 2MB.  The stack limit on Windows is 1MB.  You'll have to use a `std::vector` (and why not).

Comment: Thanks Paul. First I didn't know that the std::vector uses the stack, neither I knew there was such a small limit.

Comment: `std::vector` doesn't use the stack.  `std::array` does, hence your problem.